# How to add column description with transform_df in Foundry?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Normally, I can add a column description with `transform` like this:

```py
from transforms.api import Input, Output, transform
from utils import COLUMN_DESCRIPTIONS


@transform(
        output=Output("/Shared/output"),
        raw=Input("/Shared/raw_input")
)
def clean_table(raw, output):
    raw = raw.dataframe()
    output.write_dataframe(
        raw,
        column_descriptions=COLUMN_DESCRIPTIONS
    )
```

Can I do a similar thing with `transform_df`?

Comment: You mention the use of `@transform_df` but attached code refers to `@transform`. Which is the case?

Comment: @CheTesta My point is how I can add a description using `transform_df`. The example code is the normal way I use with `transform`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to output column descriptions with `transform_df`, you have to use the `transform` decorator for this. This is because `transform_df` returns a native Spark DataFrame, which doesn't support column descriptions.

More information about column descriptions is available in the [Palantir docs on column metadata](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/output-column-metadata/#column-descriptions).